# How to implement JSON web token on front end side?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I am working on a nodejs express application. I used Passport's JSON web token for authentication. I have successfully created a JSON web token and it's working fine in Postman and also verifies when token passes into authorization. But I stuck on front-end side.

```
app.get('/profile',passport.authenticate('jwt',{session:false}),function(req,res){
        // res.json({user:user.req});
        // console.log(req.query.token);
        res.json('bingo u cant see this without token')
    });
```

How do I send the token in the headers like I did in Postman to this (`/profile`) route, i.e how to implement token on front end side so that it first checks token?

Comment: You set it in the headers, whatever way you are doing the requests. How are you making requests?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the kind what you are using to make your request at the frontend
if you are using ajax, do something like this

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {
        "authToken":"your token" //you could save it in localstorage when recieved
    }
    //OR
    //beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
    //  xhr.setRequestHeader("My-First-Header", "first value"); 
    //  xhr.setRequestHeader("My-Second-Header", "second value"); 
    //}
 })
```

and if it's axios try doing it like this

```
post(url, {
    headers: { authToken: token }
})
```

Comment: I just want simply when user give credential then it should redirect to profile page with verification of token and token is not authorized then it should not display the page.